# List all dependencies used by a particular dependency in a Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods

For example, my Podfile has

pod x
   pod y
   pod z

When I run `pod install`, it installs 'a', 'b', and 'c', in addition to 'x', 'y', and 'z'.
If I want to find out where 'a' comes from, (is it from 'x' or 'y' or 'z', or do they share), how do I find out?

Comment: Maybe someone has a nice command for it, but I usually look at the Podfile.lock. Under the `PODS` section, the Pods are listed. Nested pods indicates that one pod is a subspec of another.

Comment: How you can open Podfile.lock??

Comment: @VipulKumar you can use whichever editor you'd like. I use VS Code, so from the command line, I type `$ code Podfile.lock`

Comment: @h.and.h thanks mate for reply. Yes, you're right :) It's late lol I already found it but good to see you still responded.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After you run `pod install` you can look in your `Podfile.lock`. Here you should see entries indented under other entries. The indented entries are dependencies of the top level entries. For example:

```
- AFNetworking (1.3.4)
- ISO8601DateFormatter (0.7)
- Mantle (1.3.1):
  - Mantle/extobjc (= 1.3.1)
- Mantle/extobjc (1.3.1)
- OctoKit (0.5):
  - AFNetworking (~> 1.3.3)
  - ISO8601DateFormatter (~> 0.7.0)
  - Mantle (~> 1.3.1)
  - ReactiveCocoa (~> 2.2.2)
- ReactiveCocoa (2.2.4):
  - ReactiveCocoa/Core (= 2.2.4)
  - ReactiveCocoa/no-arc (= 2.2.4)
- ReactiveCocoa/Core (2.2.4):
  - ReactiveCocoa/no-arc
- ReactiveCocoa/no-arc (2.2.4)
```

Here `Mantle` is a dependency of `OctoKit` and `Mantle/etcobjc` is a dependency of `Mantle` (although this is a subspec).

You could also look at the dependencies of specific specs by running `pod spec cat AFNetworking`. This will print the contents of the most recent `AFNetworking.podspec.json` and you can see under the `dependencies` JSON keys what it depends on. In this case you may have to look at the subspecs to see what they depend on as well.

Comment: Is there a way of getting this list without actually installing the pods?

Comment: You can try using [`cocoapods-dependencies`](https://github.com/segiddins/cocoapods-dependencies) for this

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that gem before, but found it to have [this issue](https://github.com/segiddins/cocoapods-dependencies/issues/16).

Comment: Any text editor should work to open it, or `cat Podfile.lock`